# Send sms from C# or VB.NET to mopile phone

Tags: c#, vb.net, sms, sms-gateway

I have tried to send an sms from C# code using Gmail but I can't find Gmail services for sending sms. I need any way to do that by Gmail or another posiibility. How can I send an sms from C# or VB.NET program to a mobile phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fairly hard to give you an accurate answer as it can depend on where you are and where you want to send SMS's to as some providers only support some countries or have issues sending  to certain networks, so make sure you know what your requirements are before choosing a provider.

In the past I've used [Clickatel](https://www.clickatell.com/), as they supported the countries and networks I needed, and their API was good enough.

The only other advice I would give is whatever service you end up using pay for it, free services are more trouble than they are worth.

Hope this helps,

Jen

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) to [Windows Azure Notification Hub servic](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/)e for this.